# How to add play two sound files with one button in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a button in VB.NET has two changeable pictures and two changeable sounds, for example: if I click the button the background of button will show pic1 and play sound1.wav then if I click again on button will show pic2 as button background and play sound2.wav

I was able to change the button background with this code but I couldn't figure out how to add two play sounds:

```
 Public Class Form1
 Dim Index As Integer = 0
 Dim Image1 As New List(Of Image)


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Index = Index Xor 1
    Button1.BackgroundImage = Image1(Index)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Image1.Add(Image.FromFile("D:\pic1.png"))
    Image1.Add(Image.FromFile("D:\pic2.png"))
End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: use `My.Computer. Audio. Play ("sound.wav")`

Comment: @preciousbetine I used it but that code only for one `wav file` I want two sounds wav files.

Comment: check out this link `https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/39b40b77-4d09-4adb-a728-18eb4397a155/play-multiple-audio-files-at-once-visual-basic?forum%3Dvbgeneral&hl=ha-NG`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image class has the tag property so you can use it to store sound paths for each image you are loading in the list.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Index As Integer = 0
    Dim Image1 As New List(Of Image)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Index = Index Xor 1
        Button1.BackgroundImage = Image1(Index)
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(Image1(Index).Tag, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Image1.Add(Image.FromFile("D:\pic1.png"))
        Image1(0).tag = "d:\sound1.wav"
        Image1.Add(Image.FromFile("D:\pic2.png"))
        Image1(1).tag = "d:\sound2.wav"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much is really very helpful :-)